# C# enabling button using datatable for loop

Tags: c#, for-loop, datatable

I am working on authorization project and I want to write code to enable authorized buttons with for loop while opening form.

Authorizated buttons cames from sql database

`row.Enabled = true;` gives me this error;

```
"datarow does not contain a definition for "Enabled" and no extension method 'Enabled' accepting a
 first argument of type 'DataRow' could be found(are you missing a
 directive reference or an assembly reference?)"
```

This is my code

```
public void yetkiver()
    {
        SqlDataAdapter adapter1903 = new SqlDataAdapter();
        SqlCommand cmd1903 = new SqlCommand("select distinct buttonname from authorization where Isactive=1 and usercode='user1'", con);

        DataTable dt1903 = new DataTable();
        DataSet ds1903 = new DataSet();

        adapter1903.SelectCommand = cmd1903;
        adapter1903.Fill(ds1903);
        dt1903 = ds1903.Tables[0];



        foreach (DataColumn col in dt1903.Columns)
        {
            foreach (DataRow row in dt1903.Rows)
            {
                row.Enabled = true;

            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: You really store the button-names in database? What if someone wants to change them?

Comment: @TimSchmelter yes i am store button names in database for user based authorization

Answer (score 1):

Of course a `DataRow` has no `Enabled` property. You want to enable the button with this name. So you have to find it on the form. You can use `Controls.Find` and LINQ:

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt1903.Rows)
{
    string buttonName = row.Field<string>("buttonname");
    Button btn = this.Controls.Find(buttonName, true).OfType<Button>().SingleOrDefault(); // throws an exception if multiple found
    if(btn != null)
       btn.Enaled = true;
}
```

This is a weird approach by the way, what if someone wants to change the button-names? I would not store the names in database but their type/meaning. Don't use a loop to find them.

Comment: Schemelter thank you very much this code is worked. Nobody can change the button names only i can update codes :)