# How to make this type of code in C# shorter?

Tags: c#, loading

Hi i want to make this code shorter:

```
tb1n.Text = Settings2.Default.tb1n;
tb2n.Text = Settings2.Default.tb2n;
tb3n.Text = Settings2.Default.tb3n;
tb4n.Text = Settings2.Default.tb4n;
tb5n.Text = Settings2.Default.tb5n;
tb6n.Text = Settings2.Default.tb6n;
tb7n.Text = Settings2.Default.tb7n;
tb8n.Text = Settings2.Default.tb8n;
tb9n.Text = Settings2.Default.tb9n;
tb10n.Text = Settings2.Default.tb10n;
tb11n.Text = Settings2.Default.tb11n;
tb12n.Text = Settings2.Default.tb12n;
tb13n.Text = Settings2.Default.tb13n;
```

Later I will add more settings to load and I need make it shorter but I don´t know how.

I tried to get this code to string like this:

```
int i = 1;
do
{
    string tbload = "tb" + i + "n.Text = Settings2.Default.tb" + i + "n";
    i++;
} while (i == 13);
```

But then I realize this is not good solution because execute code from string is hard to do and I don´t like it.

Comment: Why i see such questions so often here? If they are so similar use a list and a control that displays a list or tabular data. If they are not similar give them meaningful names. Similar question two days ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882933/c-sharp-enabling-button-using-datatable-for-loop/47883276#47883276 Other answered two days ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47883307/use-an-alternative-of-if-statement-for-checkboxes/47883371#47883371

Comment: Why no use a *list* of controls instead of having 13? Then you could easily set the value of the element of index i.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create visual tree helper class and find all textbox instances on view.

**Helper class:**

```
public static class TreeHelper
    {
        public static IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(this DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
        {
            if (depObj == null) yield break;

            for (var i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
            {
                var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
                var children = child as T;
                if (children != null)
                    yield return children;

                foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
                    yield return childOfChild;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Call**

```
var children = this.FindVisualChildren<TextBox>();
foreach (var child in children)
{
   child.Text = Settings.Default[child.Name].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store your TextBoxes and your strings in a list like this:

```
        List<TextBox> TextBoxes = new List<TextBox>() {
            tb1n,
            tb2n,
            tb3n,
            ...
        };

        List<string> mySettings = new List<string>(){
            Settings2.Default.tb1n,
            Settings2.Default.tb2n,
            Settings2.Default.tb3n,
            ...
        };

        foreach  (TextBox item in TextBoxes)
        {
            item.Text = mySettings[TextBoxes.FindIndex(a => a.Name == item.Name)];
        }
```

And then you can use a foreach loop to give every TextBox it's Text property value.